# Not able to setDates on datepicker with multidate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i tried to load some Dates into the `Datepicker`, but have no clue why it is only loading the

```
new Date(2014,10,10);
```

but not

```
new Date(); // or
new Date(2014,10,10,11);
```

initialised dates.
Here is what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/BSyqF/

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap datepicker asks for local Dates

When you're using the date like:

```
 new Date(2014,10,10,11);
```

You're adding the hours to it and in the documentation of the [setDates](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#setdates) method it asks for local dates, because they will be converted to their UTC representation.

```
Date.UTC(2014,10,10) = 1415577600000

Date.UTC(2014,10,10,11) = 1415617200000
```

So since we have a part of hours the miliseconds value changes and I think the datepicker is searching exactly for the UTC value of the dates without any hour minutes or seconds.

That's the same with the `new Date()` value since it contains the time part

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BSyqF/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. So i have to use `Date(old.getFullYear(),old.getMonth(),old.getDate())` etc. to get it working or is there a more efficient way? http://jsfiddle.net/BSyqF/4/

Comment: Yes using this it will create the date without hours, minutes and seconds :)